# How to get the describe tables from the Redshift and ALTER it

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have create a redshift cluster and created a db inside.

My schema is `new_schema`

I have created 2 tables inside two tables inside `table1`, `table2`

My Question.

1. I want to list the datatypes of table1
2. I need to change the datatype of `description` which is inside the `table1` which is of `VARCHAR` to `TEXT`

I have tried to list the datatypes of table1 with below query `but nothing listing`

`SELECT * FROM PG_TABLE_DEF WHERE schemaname = 'new_schema';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few possibilities as to why you are not seeing the expected results.  Most likely is that new_schema isn't in your search_path.  Pg_table_info only return info for tables in your search_path - see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_PG_TABLE_DEF.html

Another possibility is that the tables have no data rows (no blocks assigned) and this can lead to incomplete info from some system tables.

Another possibility is that the tables were not committed by the creating session and being checked by a different session.  Since you say that you are creating a new db this comes to mind.

Are the tables visible in svv_table_info?

Also the premise of changing varchar to text is a bit off.  From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html#r_Character_types-text-and-bpchar-types

> You can create an Amazon Redshift table with a TEXT column, but it is
> converted to a VARCHAR(256) column that accepts variable-length values
> with a maximum of 256 characters.

So it seems like the objective you are trying to achieve is a bit off.